# Combination of AND and JGE in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

I have the following assembly lines which I do not understand exactly:

```
...
AND EDX, 0x80000003
JGE SHORT prog.00401304
...
```

Normally I have always seen the `JGE` instruction after `CMP` instruction. 
With a `CMP` I must look if the first operand is greater or equal than the second operand. 
But with and `AND`, I do not know. 
Can somebody tell me how I must interpret it with and `AND` instruction?
Should I perform the `AND` operation on `EDX` with the value 0x80000003? And then?
How it can look in a pseudo-C code language?

Answer (score 2):

`and` modifies `flags` in the following way (See Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual Combined Volumes:1, 2A, 2B, 2C, 3A, 3B and 3C):

```
Flags Affected
The OF and CF flags are cleared; the SF, ZF, and PF flags are set according to
the result. The state of the AF flag is undefined.
```

`jge` means "Jump if greater or equal (SF=OF)", it's synonymous with `jnl`. See [Intel x86 JUMP quick reference](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/x86-jumps.html).

As `OF` (overflow flag) is always cleared (set to zero) after `and`, and `jge` jumps when (SF=OF), `jge` after `and` jumps when `SF` is set to zero, that is, when the highest bit of the result (here `edx` is set to zero), which means that the signed result is zero or positive integer (0..2147483647).

Answer (score 0):

You should have consulted the instruction set reference.

`JGE` operates based on flag bits, namely: `Jump if greater or equal (SF=OF)`.
Okay, now you need to figure out the value of those flags. You turn to the page describing the operation of the `AND` instruction and see: `The OF and CF flags are cleared; the SF, ZF, and PF flags are set according to the result`. `0x80000003` has the highest bit set, thus after the `AND` operation `SF` gets the highest bit of `EDX` (also known as the sign bit). All in all, the branch is taken if the `EDX >= 0`, because then `SF`=`OF`=`0`.

Answer (score 0):

NRZ explained that OK. I will add that JGE in that code is equivalent to JNS.
A small piece of C-code that produces these assembly instructions is:

```
test( ) {
    int i;
    i &= 0x80000003;
    if( i < 0 ) i = -i;
}
```

If you compile it with

```
cl /c /FAs test.c
```

the listing (part of it ) is :

```
; 2    :    int i;
; 3    :    i &= 0x80000003;
mov eax, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
and eax, -2147483645            ; 80000003H
mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], eax
; 4    :    if( i < 0 ) i = -i;
jge SHORT $LN2@test
mov ecx, DWORD PTR _i$[ebp]
neg ecx
mov DWORD PTR _i$[ebp], ecx

$LN2@test:
```

Keep in mind that the MOV instruction after AND does not affect flags.

I hope this helps.

Comment: True, `jge` after `and` is functionally identical to `jns`. However, if `jge` instruction itself is a jump target from somewhere else (for obfuscation or some other reason), then `jge` and `jns` may obviously produce different kinds of behavior.

Comment: You' right, but I wrote "in that code". BTW it looks like the output of some disassembler, and has no indication that it (JGE) is target of another jump.